# Add mathematical symbol, letter, and stored value in an R plot with bquote

Tags: r, plot, text, expression

I am trying to add one mathematical symbol and one letter plus a stored value to a plot in R. The expression without Delta does work but when trying to combine them, I struggle to get the correct code.

What I want to have in the end is the following expression, **additionally** with a bar horizontally on top of ΔT:

```
ΔT = 1.5
```

What I got so far:

```
text(xpos, ypos, bquote(bar(T) == .(format(temp, digits = 2))), adj = 1)
```

1.5 is stored in a vector named temp, xpos and ypos indicate specific coordinates in the plot area. The line gives me the expression above but without the Delta.

I tried several versions to write the code line and gave the expression() call a try, too, but nothing worked yet.

Any idea on what I am missing here? It can only be a small detail...

Comment: Try: `bquote(Delta~bar(T) == .(format(temp, digits = 2)))`  Adding the space "~" seems to work.

Comment: Yes, the space `~` does the trick! Just had to slightly modify your line as follows so I get the bar on top of both the Delta and the T. `bquote(bar(Delta~T) == .(format(temp, digits = 2)))` is the line that works nicely.